# Prove that for all $c \in [0,\infty)$ there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $xe^x=c$ by the intermediate value theorem

Tags: analysis, continuity

As the title suggests I am trying to prove that for all $c \in [0,\infty)$ there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $xe^x=c$.

Now, the previous parts of this question imply that the way we are meant to do this is by using the intermediate value theorem. Then we can consider $xe^x = f(x)$, but this function is defined on $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and the IVT requires that our domain be $[a,b]$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. So how exactly can we do this? Please note that this comes from an analysis course so calc I or II methods won't work here.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the domain is all $\mathbb{R}$. For a specific $c$ show there are points $a,b$ such that $f(a)<c$ and $f(b)>c$ (or vice versa), and then restrict the domain to $[a, b]$.

Comment: @Mark So, are we permitted to pick an interval based on c? As in, we don't need to find a 'god' interval that captures every possible c?

Comment: Yes, the interval depends on $c$. If you take a specific interval $[a,b]$ then the function is bounded there (by Weierstrass theorem), and so there is no way this interval will work for all values $c\in [0,\infty)$. So for different values of $c$ you need different intervals.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

If $ c=0$, we will take $ x=0$.

So, let us assume that $ c>0$.

the function $ f : x\mapsto xe^x $ satisfies
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0\;;\;\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty $$

So, there exist $ \delta>0 $ and $ A>0 $ such that
$$a\le \delta \implies f(a)<\frac c2$$
and
$$b\ge A \implies f(b)>2c$$

Now, apply IVT to $ g:x\mapsto f(x)-c $

at the intervall  $[a,b] $.